# Accessing the properties of an IEnumerable

Tags: c#, twitter, ienumerable, tweetinvi

I'm using TweetInvi to grab a bunch of tweets that match a specified hashtag. I do this with the following:

```
var matchingTweets = Search.SearchTweets(hashtag);
```

This returns an IEnumerable (named `ITweet`, interface of `Tweet`), however I cannot create a `List<>` of `Tweets`, because `Tweet` is a static type.

I made, instead, a list of `objects`, using:

```
List<object> matches = matchingTweets.Cast<object>().ToList();
```

However, although each member of the `matchingTweets` IEnumerable has a number of properties, I cannot access them using:

```
long tweetID = matches[i].<property>;
```

Using `matches[i].ToString()` returns the tweet content, so how can I effectively cast the results in `matchingTweets` to a list, and subsequently access the properties of those list members? I would ideally like to avoid using `dynamic`.

Comment: What property do you need to access?

Comment: Whatever type is in the `IEnumerable` cannot be static, that's just not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example above you were trying to grab the ID from the tweet.  `ITweet` implements `ITweetIdentifier` which contains the `Id` property.  You can literally just access it by:

```
var matchingTweets = Search.SearchTweets(hashtag);

//Grab the first 5 tweets from the results.
var firstFiveTweets = matchingTweets.Take(5).ToList();

//if you only want the ids and not the entire object
var firstFiveTweetIds = matchingTweets.Take(5).Select(t => t.Id).ToList();

//Iterate through and do stuff
foreach (var tweet in matchingTweets)
{
    //These are just examples of the properties accessible to you...
    if(tweet.Favorited)
    {
        var text = tweet.FullText;
    }     
    if(tweet.RetweetCount > 100)
    {
        //TODO: Handle popular tweets...
    }   
}

//Get item at specific index
matchingTweets.ElementAt(index);
```

I don't know exactly what you want to do with all the info, but since the `SearchTweets` returns a IEnumerable of `ITweets` you have access to anything an [ITweet](https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/blob/b28eb6091ad86d3758a5a3d8cf66e762c2b9d7ff/Tweetinvi.Core/Public/Models/Interfaces/ITweet.cs) has defined.

I highly recommend looking through their [wiki](https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/wiki).  It's pretty well organized and gives you clear examples of some basic tasks.

Comment: Can I access a specific tweet in matchingTweets?

Comment: If you know its Id or some other bit of info you can use LINQ.  I updated my answer with how to grab a tweet by an id.

Comment: That's just it - I *don't* know the ID of any of the tweets, but I want to pull the ID's of the first five in the results

Comment: Updated to take the first 5 returned from the search

Comment: I've just realised that this is easily done with a foreach loop, but how would one access specific tweets within the results where, for example, one wishes to access the 10th, 20th and 47th tweet?

Comment: `matchingTweets.ElementAt(index)`

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense you cannot access the properties. You cast it into `object` so you can only access the `object`s properties and methods (that like you said might have been overridden).

It should be fine to just access it like this:

```
List<ITweet> tweets = matchingTweets.Take(5).ToList();
```

What you can do is project it to a new object of yours:

```
var tweets = matchingTweets.Select(item => new {
                                       property1 = item.property1,
                                       property2 = item.property2
                                   })
                           .Take(5).ToList();
```

Then you will be able to access what you need. Now, if you need to share this data outside the scope of that function create a DTO object and initialize it instead of the anonymous type.

Depending on the size of the project and amount of effort usually it is in any case a good practice to create a layer of DTO objects when you interact with an external service like this. Then if their models changed you can contain your changes only to the DTOs.

---

If all you want are the ids of the first 5 then:

```
var ids = matchingTweets.Take(5).Select(item => item.id).ToList();
```

Comment: @Wolfish - if you want to pull the results of the first 5 then check update

Comment: Just to note - Your answer also works, but @maccettura provided an a answer within the context of TweetInvi, which was more relevant here, hence the selection of his answer as the "chosen" answer.